# ¿Como pasar el valor de una variable entre dos eventos click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar y decirme que estoy realizando mal de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo una aplicación de 3 capas en asp.net donde al dar clic a un botón realizo una consulta con a mi base de datos el cual me regresa una url de imagen.

Mi pregunta es como pasar ese  valor de la imagen a otro evento clic sin utilizar variables de sesión.

Aquí coloco mi código espero puedan ayudarme.

```
public partial class Ejemplo
{
  string url_imagen;


  // Aquí se llama el procedimiento almacenado que me retorna el valor de la imagen y se lo asigno a mi variable local
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        capa_transacciones transaccion = new capa_transacciones();

        DataSet datos = new DataSet();
        DataTable datos_imagen = new DataTable();

        DataRow row;
        datos = transaccion.Url_imagen();

        datos_imagen = datos.Tables[0];
        row = datos_imagen.Rows[0];
        url_imagen = row[1].ToString(); // Le asigno el valor a la variable. Al poner punto de interrupción la variable contiene datos.

   }

   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
          // Aquí quiero asignarle a un control imagen el valor de la variable anterior.
       Mostrar_imagen.Src = url_imagen; // El valor de la imagen es null

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias usar el objeto `ViewState` para asignar el valor y accederlo entre eventos

[ViewState Example in ASP.Net](https://meeraacademy.com/viewstate-example-in-asp-net/)

implementarlo es igual al objeto `Session` solo que el valor no queda en el servidor sino que se envia como parte del contenido de la pagina al cliente

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //resto codigo

     ViewState["urlimagen"] = row[1].ToString();
}
```

y lo recuperas usando

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url_imagen =ViewState["urlimagen"].ToString():

    Mostrar_imagen.Src = url_imagen; 

}
```